# Ruby/Bash script to backup my table and delete records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I'm save all the transactions in DB instead of logs , but i don't want the table to get huge and slow , so I was thinking to create a cron job to do something every few month like :

1- Backup the table for hard drive 
2- move all the records to a new table something like table_backup
3- delete the records on that table

This way in case insert will take lot of time with huge table, the table will be freed every few months

Please not that I'm using ruby with active record models to access the DB tables , what do you think the best way to do such a thing , and is there any alternatives to what I suggested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. **Redundancy** - depending on how critical your data is, you may want redundant storage (e.g. a master-slave database setup, or the database on a RAID device)
2. **Backups** - have hourly/daily/weekly backups (again, depending on how critical it is to maintain these backups, how much space you can afford for them, how much traffic you're getting, and what the impact is on the database) of the entire database.
3. **Truncation** - have a cron task (check out the `whenever` gem which makes this easy) that deletes all entries older than some threshold (2 weeks?). There's no need to populate a new table just to delete old entries.

I believe these approaches are orthogonal, so you can pick whichever ones suit you, or implement the important one(s) first.

Comment: Orthogonal? You mean they have 8 sides?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `octocatogonal`, as in github-worthy.